# Update leaflet baselayer properties with GoogleMutant

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I have a google layer (baselayer) GoogleMutant   and want to update its options. I try to

```
map.remove(google.layer)
//update the POI visibility
google.layer.options.styles.forEach(i=>i.stylers[0].visibility = "off")
map.addLayer(google.layer)
```

this updates the layer options but the `Points of interest` are still on the map. Is there any way to update the options and apply them to the baselayer?
Thanks

Here is an example with google mutant https://jsfiddle.net/benderlio/2m4c01w6/10/
There is a button "remove POI", and I want to remove all poi from current layer with leaflet API

Comment: Are we talking about GoogleMutant here?

Comment: @IvanSanchez yes, sorry for not mentioning this

Comment: Please edit your question to include some relevant initialization code - how are you instantiating GoogleMutant, and what options is it getting at the beginning?

Comment: Where is the data you render on the map and you want to remove? Could you create a small demo to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: @kboul I added an example. All I want to do is remove POI from the current layer (update the options of the googleMutant `stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]`) with the map API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet doesn't work changing settings on the fly. You have to remove the whole object and create a substitute.

Like if you need to change a layer, you have to remove it like:

```
roadMutant.removeFrom(map); // or
map.removeLayer(roadMutant);
```

And then create and add the new one:

```
roadMutant.addTo(map);
```

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zv0uac1f/2/) to help the change based on yours. It still have bugs and somewhere to grow, but it's a base...